# php, sql selection

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a stupid question, I have this table :

```
id_product    name        value
   1          price       10-20
   1          type        computer
   2          price       20-30
   3          price       100-200
```

and I want to select from this table GROUP BY id_product and ORDER BY value WHERE name='price'

how can i do this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: write your query and just make sure that WHERE clause comes first

Comment: is it the very first SQL query you're going to execute in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from table_name  WHERE name='price' 
    GROUP BY id_product
    ORDER BY value
```

In PHP

```
mysql_query("select * from table_name  WHERE name='price' 
        GROUP BY id_product
        ORDER BY value") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: `select * from table_name 
    GROUP BY id_product
    ORDER BY (select t.value FROM table_name t WHERE name='price' AND t.id_product = table_name.id_product)`

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE name = 'price'
GROUP BY id_product
ORDER BY value
```

You can see [this for MySQL Select syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

Answer (score 2):

select * from table_name where name='price' Group By id_product ORDER By value;

Answer (score 1):

right off the top of my head...

does it work?

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `table`.`name`='price' GROUP BY `table`.id_product ORDER BY `table`.`value` ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you want to group items with the same id: which one do you want to be shown? In theory `GROUP BY` shouldn't be used with `SELECT *` (it does not work with non mysql databases) and should be associated with aggregate funcions such as `COUNT()`, `MAX()`, etc.

You might just need `SELECT DISTINCT` instead of `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

This will select distinct `id_product` from `table_name` and order by `value` where `name` is "price". I think this will give the outcome you're after.

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_product 
FROM table_name 
ORDER BY (
    SELECT t.value FROM table_name t 
    WHERE t.name='price'
    AND t.id_product = table_name.id_product
)
```